# Can dapper take a scalar (and so anonymous) parameter?

Tags: dapper

Can I do something like

```
db.Query<Thing>("Select * from Things where id=?", 1)
```

with Dapper, or is param with named fields —

```
db.Query<Thing>("Select * from Things where id= @id", new {id=1});
```

the only valid syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like the short answer is, No.

You must use `new{id=1}` or somesuch